# How to make Emoji on wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, emoji

im junior wpf developer and i was asked to make an emoji controller for our app, i need to make a picker and render them on a richtextbox. I started the project today by making a list of images , a pop up where you can pick the emoji and add it to the current caret but this is really small and im here to take ideas on how you guys did that. Another idea was to include a folder full of images and rename them with the unicode that represents each emoji from
[here](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) and render it real time.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a button that triggers the `win + .` action that shows a list of emojis (integrated with windows 10 by default btw)

Emoji picker :

[image: emojipickerw10]

`SendKeys.Send("+(.)")` should work

Comment: what if the user has windows 7?